# How to update image for just selected image (onclick)?

Tags: c#, html

Is there a way to change only one image upon clicking the image, even when there are two other columns in a table that is using that image? For instance, I have a `Apple` column and a `Banana` column. Both use the image tag as so `<img src="DefaultImg" @onclick="@(ImgSelector(""))">`.

In other words, if I select the column **Apple** once, then I should see Apple.png and the **Banana** column should still be the Basket.png. But when I do this, if I select **Apple** column once, then I will see both Apple.png in the two columns instead of just the **Apple** column.

So I have `<img src="DefaultImg" @onclick="@(ImgSelector("Apple"))">` and `<img src="DefaultImg" @onclick="@(ImgSelector("Banana"))">`

Where `DefaultImg` is "Basket.png".

```
protected void ImgSelector(string selectedColumn)
{
    

    if (value == 0)
    {
        string appleImg = "Apple.png";
        string bananaImg = "Banana.png";

        value = 1;


        switch (selectedColumn)
        {
            case "Apple":
                DefaultImg = appleImg;
                break;
            case "Banana":
                DefaultImg = bananaImg;
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string appleImg2 = "Apple2.png";
        string bananaImg2 = "Banana2.png";
        value = 0;

        switch (selectedColumn)
        {
           case "Apple":
                DefaultImg = appleImg2;
                break;
            case "Banana":
                DefaultImg = bananaImg2;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the value of DefaultImg from basekt to appleImg or bananaImg within the switch case. Since BananaColumn is using DefaultImg as source and you changed DefaultImg to be an Apple, it is no longer displaying a basket.
Instead change the src value of the image container.

Not sure how the Code in C# for Web looks like but you should get the ID of the sender element and change its HTML src tag to "appleImg"